# How to limit potential mysql performance issues caused by querying users?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have some people that need to perform query on my Db,
this is mostly done by using workbench. 
The pro of letting them querying directly the DB instead of providing them a service is that I don't need to set up a service anytime they need different data.
The cons and my worry is that they may launch (potentially) queries that may cause the mysql process to hang...

What's the way(is there some?) to limit the resource that a mysql user may occupy by querying? (I'm thinking something like configuring a short query timeout per user... or maybe there's something better.)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no.

Some people have invented a "long query killer".  It is a moderately simple script that repeatedly does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` an kills any query that has been running longer than N seconds.